# Synchronizing a Voltage Source Signal with a Database Signal in Simulink

Tags: synchronization, signals, processing, simulink

I'm working on a project in Simulink where I need to synchronize a real-time voltage source signal with a voltage signal extracted from a csv file. Both signals are at 60Hz, but they may be out of phase with each other. My objective is to align them in phase and output them simultaneously in Simulink.

Details of the Problem:

I have a voltage source in Simulink generating a 60Hz signal.
Separately, I have a database containing a voltage signal, also at 60Hz with a 30kHz sampling. However, its phase might not be aligned with the voltage source block signal when I run the simulation.
I'm facing challenges in synchronizing

Specific Questions:

What are the best practices or techniques in Simulink for achieving real-time signal synchronization, especially for aligning the phases of two such signals?
Are there specific Simulink blocks or MATLAB functions that are particularly useful for this type of phase synchronization?
Any guidance, tips, or examples on how to approach this synchronization issue would be immensely helpful. Thank you for your assistance!

The Challenge:

My objective is to synchronize these two signals in phase within Simulink. I need the output of both signals to be perfectly aligned in terms of their phase.
However, I haven't attempted any specific method or strategy to achieve this synchronization. I'm currently in the planning phase and looking for the best approach to tackle this issue.

What I'm Looking For:

I am seeking advice on methods or techniques that can be used in Simulink for real-time signal synchronization, specifically focusing on aligning the phases of these two signals.
Any suggestions on Simulink blocks or MATLAB functions that could facilitate this synchronization process would be greatly appreciated.
I am quite new to this aspect of signal processing in Simulink and would highly value any insights or recommendations on how to proceed.